# Use a chicagoboss built in filter in the code (outside of a template)

Tags: filter, erlang, chicagoboss

I was using filter `add`  to create dynamic tab indexes

```
{{tabindex_offset|add:1}}
```

But seems to be it's throwing error for an `undefined` tabindex_offset.
So wanted to add custom filter like this:

```
add_by_custom(undefined, Count) ->Count;
add_by_custom(TabindexOffset, Count) ->
       chicagoboss_built_in_filter_module:add(TabindexOffset, Count).
```

Is there any way to call that built in filter in the code?